# Как вызвать функцию с аргументами по умолчанию из шаблонной функции без указания значений для аргументов по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, аргументы

Я попробовал следующий код:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <functional>

    int anyFunc(int a, int b, int c = 0, int d = 0) {
        return a + b + c + d;
    }

    template <class T, class F>
    T callFunc2(const std::function<F> & func, T a, T b) {
        return func(a, b);
    }

    int main() {
        std::cout << callFunc2<int, decltype(anyFunc)>(anyFunc, 5, 5) << std::endl;
    }
```

Но он выдает ошибку.
GCC 9.3.0:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'T callFunc2(const std::function<_Signature>&, T, T) [with T = int; F = int(int, int, int, int)]':
prog.cc:14:65:   required from here
prog.cc:10:16: error: no match for call to '(const std::function<int(int, int, int, int)>) (int&, int&)'
   10 |     return func(a, b);
      |            ~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-9.3.0/include/c++/9.3.0/functional:59,
                 from prog.cc:2:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-9.3.0/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/std_function.h:683:5: note: candidate: '_Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {int, int, int, int}]'
  683 |     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-9.3.0/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/std_function.h:683:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
```

Т. е. нужно указать 4 аргумента вместо 2. Но почему? Ведь 2 аргумента по умолчанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откуда компилятору знать о том, *что именно* вызывается в шаблоне? По-вашему, это может быть и функция от двух, и от четырех аргументов... Аргументы по умолчанию - это не более чем подсказка для конкретного явного вызова функции.
*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Как всегда, спасает косвенность :)

```
#include <iostream>

int anyFunc(int a, int b, int c = 0, int d = 0) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}


template <class T, class F>
T callFunc4(F func, T a, T b, T c = T(), T d = T()) {
    return func(a, b, c, d);
}

template <class T, class F>
T callFunc2(F func, T a, T b) {
    return func(a, b);
}


int main() {
    std::cout << callFunc4(anyFunc, 5, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << callFunc2([](int a, int b){ return anyFunc(a,b); }, 5, 5) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что если не использовать lambda-функцию (и оставить anyFunc и callFunc2 как есть), то есть лишь один вариант — передавать новую функцию (например, anyFunc2: с другим именем), которая вызывает anyFunc, в callFunc2. Или есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Ну, "я не волшебник, я только учусь", так что может и есть, но я не вижу иного пути, либо как промежуточный вызываемый объект (функция, лямбда...), либо сам шаблон для функции от четырех переменных с аргументами по умолчанию...  - https://ideone.com/5Jku46

Answer (score 2):

Этот пример показывает, что аргументов по-умолчанию следует избегать и использовать вместо них перегруженные функции.

```
int anyFunc(int a, int b, int c) {
        return anyFunc(a, b, c, 0);
    }
int anyFunc(int a, int b) {
        return anyFunc(a, b, 0);
    }
```

В этом случае также будет возможность при необходимости поставить точку останова при вызове функции с аргументами по-умолчанию. Также эти аргументы не будут создаваться в вызывающем коде (для int это не важно, но с при работе с более большими объектами - очень даже).